# CSS columns maintain same height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to setup some css to have 3 columns.

With the middle and the right column able to have text in them.  I have it currently so that the middle column will wrap text and all the other columns will resize based on that column.  I need the right column to affect the other columns in the same manner.  I'm no CSS expert and code mainly in C#.

I've tried other solutions and this is the closest I've gotten to what I desire.  Any thoughts?

The CSS so far:

```
#outer
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding:0;
}

#leftcolumn
{
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;    
margin: 0 ;
background-color: Yellow;
z-index:10;    
left:0px;
top:0; 
}

#rightcolumn
{
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 75px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;    
margin: 0 ;
background-color: green;
right:0px;
top:0; 
}

#middlecolumn
{
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;    
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:75px;
background-color: #62A9FF;
left:0px;
top:0px; 
}

#inner
{
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;    
position: relative;
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); 
-webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6eshT/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy using `display: table-cell;`.

Comment: Tried the table-cell approach and failed because needed to support ie8+

Comment: This actually worked.  It wasn't initially working for me because I didn't have <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" /> so it wasn't rendering properly in IE8.  Alexandr Skachkov, thanks for posting the jsfiddle it was very helpful.  jsfiddle.net/kLMtb/show.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can do this with straight CSS, but you can use jQuery to achieve this pretty easily.

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6eshT/8/

Basically, you set all the columns to have the same class name. Have at least one common class, ie `class="col somethingElse"` The "somethingElse" can be a class specific to style each column.

jQuery would be:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var max = -1;
    $(".col").each(function() {
        var h = $(this).height(); 
        max = h > max ? h : max;
    });
    $(".col").css({ 'height' : max })
});
```

Comment: That is a great solution.  However with my environment I am limited and am unable to use jquery.  Pretty much using microsoft's html editor in C#.  So it's an htmleditor in a c# application.  I got it to work with 2 columns.. It's just the third one that's throwing me off..

Comment: Actually, what you have only works if the center column is the largest, which is due to your use of position absolute. If you think outside the box a little, you can link to an external jquery library(<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>) and simply put the jquery in my answer below that between `<script type="text/javascript">` and a closing `</script>` tag. It should work like a charm ;)

Comment: Couple things beyond my control forbids me from doing that.  Also I tried to make the conenteditable and it doesn't adjust the height when content is added..  http://jsfiddle.net/6eshT/14/

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think its possible with your limitations. You could always assign a height to all three. Won't allow the columns to resize, but would only effect you if there was too much content. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah I appreciate the help though.  I managed to implement a solution that will get me by but really doesn't solve this problem.  Basically I just made the right column scrollable with a simple overflow:auto.  The middle column is primary content and the right is optional/low priority.  So the middle will determine the size in the editor.

Comment: If you don't mind, please upvote helpful answers. I know that every question does not get answered, but some questions are helpful. Your case is very unique, but some of the answers on here are good and deserve an upvote. Good luck!

Comment: I upvoted answers, if you saw a one next to it that was me :P  Just upvoted yours.  Sorry I'm just back and forth doing things.

Comment: It's all good. I honestly did not care if you upvoted mine, I just saw a couple good answers and thought they should be upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make multiple columns all the same height is with faux columns. 
http://line25.com/articles/create-sidebars-of-equal-height-with-faux-columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:flexbox more about this
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I like this, unfortunately I need something compatible with ie8+

Comment: You can use display:table, table-cell as mntion before. Please check following question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202019/css-3-column-liquid-layout-dynamic-same-height-column?rq=1) and example from answer work in IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/kLMtb/show/.

Comment: Alexandr Skachkov, thanks.  after investigating my code I found it wasn't rendering in ie8 properly.  I had to add the meta tag <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />.  Afterwards it worked perfectly.