# Content pushed above viewport with hash in url

Tags: html, css

I was happily using [3 column layout](http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail) as detailed in alistapart.com. It worked perfectly unless there are hashed url. So my center column content shows perfectly for http://www.jahajee.com/CDC-Renewal-Procedure/7890/1.html but content goes missing when the url changes to http://www.jahajee.com/CDC-Renewal-Procedure/7890/1.html#24873 .

I found the CSS `#container .column{padding-bottom:10010px;margin-bottom:-10000px;}` to be the problem ! The said css rule is required to make all 3 `column` of equal height with a `container` defined wrapping the 3 column. When I remove this condition the content stays in the viewport but columns are of unequal height !

The relevant CSS

```
#container{padding-left:200px;padding-right:240px;overflow:hidden;}
#container .column{position:relative;float:left;padding-bottom:10010px;margin-bottom:-10000px;}
#centre{width:100%;padding:10px 20px;}
#left{width:180px;padding:0 10px;right:240px;margin-left:-100%;background:#dfebfd;}
#right{width:180px;padding:0 10px;margin-right:-240px;}
```

The content also shows up when the `container overflow:hidden` is removed but then the page takes full length of 10000px !

I also tried to make `container` `display:table` and the columns `display:table-cell` as recommended in [CSS 3 Column Liquid Layout Dynamic Same Height Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202019/css-3-column-liquid-layout-dynamic-same-height-column) but then the columns are not of equal height !

Can someone please guide which parameters can be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior seems to be the default behavior with this solution. See: http://jsfiddle.net/qm3z9p2q/ This is the solution from alistapart with the padding-bottom, margin-bottom solution to make the columns equal in height.

To use display:table and display:table-cell is a complete different solution. See: http://jsfiddle.net/qm3z9p2q/1/

There is a third solution with faux columns using border-color as background-color for the left and right columns. See: http://jsfiddle.net/qm3z9p2q/3/
This will only work, if the center column ever is the highest column. And it needs a clearing element after the columns, see the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Faux columns with border-color</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        /*** The Essential Code ***/

        body {
            min-width: 550px;         /* 2 x LC width + RC width */
        }

        #container {
            border-left: 200px solid #66F;      /* LC width */
            border-right: 150px solid #F66;     /* RC width */
        }

        #container .column {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
        }

        #center {
            width: 100%;
        }

        #left {
            width: 200px;             /* LC width */
            right: 200px;             /* LC width */
            margin-left: -100%;
        }

        #right {
            width: 150px;             /* RC width */
            margin-right: -100%;
        }

        #footer {
            clear: both;
        }

        /*** IE6 Fix ***/
        * html #left {
            left: 150px;              /* RC width */
        }

        /*** Just for Looks ***/

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: #FFF;
        }

        #header, #footer {
            font-size: large;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0.3em 0;
            background: #999;
        }

        #left {
        }

        #center {
            background: #DDD;

        }

        #right {
        }

        #container .column {
            padding-top: 1em;
            text-align: justify;
        }

        p#i12345 {
                        margin-top:50em;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header">This is the header.</div>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="center" class="column">
            <h1>This is the main content.</h1>

<p><a href="#i12345">jump to ID i12345</a></p>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla.</p>
            <p id="i12345">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="left" class="column">
            <h2>This is the left sidebar.</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="right" class="column">
            <h2>This is the right sidebar.</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla.</p>
        </div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">This is the footer.</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I ended up using Faux column but with background image and it worked perfectly.